# Error Message is not clear to me

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

i Keep getting this error message and can't figure out why? 
Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void gettickvalue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        int n = RandomNumber.Next(1, 9);

        imgBanner.ImageUrl = System.String.Concat("Timer/banner_", n.ToString(), ".jpg");
    }
```

Comment: you are missing closing braces `}` , add the curly braces `}` at the end of your code

Comment: The error message is pretty specific, the compiler expected a "}". Seems pretty obvious, you're missing a "}"

Comment: Try Google. Searching [c# } expected](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+%7D+expected&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS566US566&oq=c%23+%7D+expected&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.2311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) found an answer instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you posted is your whole class, you're missing a curly brace. Exactly as the error message says.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void gettickvalue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        int n = RandomNumber.Next(1, 9);
        imgBanner.ImageUrl = String.Concat("Timer/banner_", n.ToString(), ".jpg");  
    }
} //we added this curly brace
```

It's easier to see where it's missing if you format your code properly. Visual Studio can do this for you, look it up to see how in your version. I'm on Visual Studio 2010 Pro, so I go to `Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document`.

Notice also that I changed your concatenation function to just be `String.Concat` instead of `System.String.Concat`. No need to put the system reference in front of it because the namespace is already referenced by your first using statement.

I also suggest you rename your function. See [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.